# Easy way to iterate through files in directory

Tags: input, literate-programming

I've already read multiple solutions where the poster iterates over the number of the files, but what I'm looking for is a simple way to iterate through the files in a directory. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
 \foreach\x in {dir/*.tex}{
     \input{/\x}
}
\end{document}
```

Also, it would be preferable for the solution to not be OS specific since sometimes I work on Windows, sometimes on Mac and sometimes on Linux. I know there should be an easy way to achieve this without cluttering the master file with a ~10 line function or using bash/python.

Comment: tex can not read directories so you are going to need to call `ls` or `dir` in an os-specific way at some point,

Comment: Then how can latex input single tex files from other directories in the first place. It doesn't make sense to me for latex not being able to read directories. Isn't the compiler in some sense aware of the directory structure of the project?

Comment: @Figaro Nope - TeX just reads the file names it's given, with in most modern setups `kpse` doing file searching

Comment: Well, in that case I believe I should go with a `\write18` solution. The lack of automation and scripting tools provided is a bit disappointing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need shell escape. One possible approach using `l3sys-shell`, which abstracts out various file functions in a platform-neutral way

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{l3sys-shell}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \inputfiles { m }
  {
    \sys_shell_split_ls:nN {#1} \l_tmpa_seq
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \input {##1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\inputfiles{dir/*.tex}

\end{document}
```

Note that the file order is not fixed here: you might therefore need to sort the `seq`.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151566/discussion-on-answer-by-joseph-wright-easy-way-to-iterate-through-files-in-direc); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.